# Mercator projection system grid problem. Grid false on QGIS but right on ArcGIS

Tags: qgis

I am actually trying to make a map similar to this, but for years 2019 and 2020.
[image]

The shapefile of the country I am using is in World Mercator (EPSG: 54004).
I tried on ArcGIS, but working on symbols transparency is really difficult. Here, longitude and latitude coordinates are well displayed on the grid (See image below).
[image: Result on ArcGIS, correct longitude latitude]

So, for symbols, I wanted to use QGIS, but I have a problem actually. I would like to have that grid to tell how are longitude and latitude and to be able to precisely show where it is displayed. But on QGIS, latitude and longitude shown are pure nonsense (See image below).

[image: results on QGIS, latitude and longitude are pure nonsense].

I already tried to setup another projection system in grid parameters. And I tried to play a little bit with my projection parameters but nothing is working.
How can I repair that ?
I'll paste my "grid" setup and my map setup below.

[image: my options]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.stackexchange! The grid CRS has to be changed to EPSG:4326 and the intervals have to be updated accordingly. The rest should be fine.

Comment: But EPSG:4326 is WGS84 right ? My manager wants it to be projected in world mercator because in Denmark, every maps are projected like that (Which is the case in my example map).

Comment: You can keep the map in world mercator but you need to change the grid CRS if you want meaninful lat/lon labels

Comment: Alright, that worked, could you explain me what was my mistake ? I was thinking that, since my projection was mercator, I was needing the same CRS for my grid ? What was my mistake thinking that way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QGIS Layouts, map CRS and grid CRS can be set independently. (It's even possible to add multiple grids in different CRS to the same map.)

In your case, the grid CRS has to be changed to EPSG:4326 and the intervals have to be updated accordingly. The rest should be fine.